# Detect scrolling in WebPage from IE extension

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I'm creating an IE extension (using VS2008, C++) that needs to *react to scrollbar events* in IE. I'm using BHO for that and I have access to IWebBrowser2 element, IHTMLDocument2 element and HWND of the parent window. I can't figure out how to access the scrollbars. I have seen codes that allows me to handle the scrollbar once I have access to them, but not how to get the scrollbar objects (or are they child window of the IE window?) themselves. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

MSHTML renders its own scrollbars instead of using the native system controls.  That's why you  can apply CSS rules to them.

What I would try is:

1. QueryInterface() the IHTMLDocument2
   object for IHTMLElement.
2. QueryInterface() that for
   IConnectionPointContainer.
3. Then call
   IConnectionPointContainer::FindConnectionPoint(DIID_HTMLElementEvents2).
4. Implement IDispatch::Invoke() and
   you should get the [OnScroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769762(VS.85).aspx)
   event when someone scrolls the
   document.
5. Rinse and repeat for sub-frames.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I use ATL, I realised I could just have another implementation of IDispEventImpl in my class. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

SInce I have  IDispatchImpl already implemented, I'm guessing I would have to override the ATL implementation of the IDispatch::Invoke method to handle events. IS it correct?
If that's the case and I have sink entries with DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, how would that be affected?
Here's how my class looks like:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CHelloWorldBHO :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CHelloWorldBHO, &CLSID_HelloWorldBHO>,
    public IObjectWithSiteImpl<CHelloWorldBHO>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IHelloWorldBHO, &IID_IHelloWorldBHO, &LIBID_HelloWorldLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public IDispEventImpl<1, CHelloWorldBHO, &DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, &LIBID_SHDocVw, 1, 1>
{
.
.
.
BEGIN_SINK_MAP(CHelloWorldBHO)
     SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, OnDocumentComplete)
     SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_BEFORENAVIGATE2, BeforeNavigate2)//Handle BeforeNavigate2
END_SINK_MAP()
.
.
.
}
```

Thanks

Edit: I discovered that when Invoke is Overwritten, OnDOcumentCOmplete is never called. How do I get around this?